# Extract POST URL using GET

Tags: html, objective-c, url, post, get

I am trying to simulate the functionality of a form in this website, but don't know exactly what the post URL looks like.

The link to the website is here:
 selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_disp_dyn_sched >> then click on Spring2013. The code I am trying to replicate is the one that happens when the user clicks Course Search and selects CS from the subject list.

You can look at the HTML file to see the values they use in their POST command. How do I see what the values look like once the button is clicked, as I am trying to replicate this and set the variables to the same values. What I need is a URL to be shown with all of the variables set to their respective values. I understand this can be done with a GET command. Can someone tell me how to extract this URL for me so I can proceed?

Comment: Try using Firebug (or similar tool) to capture the HTTP session.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I edited the page using chrome inspector and changed the form action to `GET` - this is the URL that was displayed.

https://selfservice.mypurdue.purdue.edu/prod/bwckschd.p_get_crse_unsec?term_in=201320&sel_subj=dummy&sel_day=dummy&sel_schd=dummy&sel_insm=dummy&sel_camp=dummy&sel_levl=dummy&sel_sess=dummy&sel_instr=dummy&sel_ptrm=dummy&sel_attr=dummy&sel_subj=CS&sel_crse=&sel_title=&sel_schd=%25&sel_from_cred=&sel_to_cred=&sel_camp=%25&sel_ptrm=%25&sel_instr=%25&sel_sess=%25&sel_attr=%25&begin_hh=0&begin_mi=0&begin_ap=a&end_hh=0&end_mi=0&end_ap=a

However, this URL dosen't resolve as the script is obviously expecting `POST` data.

Comment: I did the same thing and got the same results. When I send these variables in a POST, I get an error. Is it because I need up go through the first page before going directly to the second page and sending a post? Does it have to do with a live session or smithing?

Comment: I don't know what you are trying to achieve - Maybe submit a question with code you have tried and any errors you have encountered, stating clearly what you want to do.